# Razor WebApp & Azure Active Directory SSO Redirect Non tenant users

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I have connected my razor web app with aad sso which works and performs as expected. However, when a user tries to login that is not part of the aad tenant, it defaults to the basic error page which then shows the tenant's name, appid etc.

Have tried majority of solutions from threads that exists. Has anyone been able to fix this?
Connected aad sso using Connected Services -> Microsoft Identity platform

Comment: what result you wanna get when a user tries to login which is not part of the aad tenant?

Comment: @TinyWang I'm wanting to redirect to a failed login page instead of displaying default microsoft one which displays the tenant id/app id

Comment: The questions you answer tend to be about MS Azure configuration, pricing, infrastructure, and other cloud-related issues, instead of being practical programming problems. StackOverflow is meant to discuss only programming questions. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
for more details. Please post your non-programming question on other platforms such as [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)
, and [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/tags/133/azure)
for immediate help. Thanks!